# J programming Language vs R Programming Language vs Incanter

Tags: clojure, statistics, programming-languages

Has anyone tried both [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/) programming language form jsoftware and [R](http://www.r-project.org/) language. After some search I faced [incanter](http://incanter.org/) which is based on clojure. I want to learn a statistical language for data analysis. Which one do you prefer? Why?

Please consider conditions below, thanks.

- productivity
- performance
- community
- library
- syntax

Comment: I added incanter to compare with other options.

Comment: I added some info on J.  I know it is an old question, but J is cool.  I threw the info up here for the community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### productivity

#### library

Productivity is much related to the accessible libraries for the given task. If it's all about statistical calculation, R has an obvious win thanks to its huge variety of libraries. However, when you have to manipulate/mingle data J can be easier to handle and it will become much, much easier as you get more skilled in J programming.

However, you can have both worlds using [R interfaces](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Interfaces/R) in J.

#### performance

R is infamous for its poor performance. You shouldn't overuse for-loops either in J or R, though. J's got decent performance. Moreover, J code is usually terser and hence easier to change/rewrite/optimize/come up with a new algorithm. I find "coming up with a new algorithm" a big win.

#### community

R's community is huge compared to J's. However you have the pros and cons. Imagine the pros and cons living in a small, friendly village and in a big city.

#### syntax

J's syntax is surprisingly consistent compared to R's. The predictability is very high once you learned the principles.

Answer (score 12):

A question similar to this was asked recently on the J forum. This was my answer:

I don't know R anywhere as well as I know J, but given that disclaimer here are my impressions:

### J

- strong mathematical focus
- conceptual framework for working with array data is very general, consistent and well thought out.
- code is succinct/terse
- object-oriented paradigm available but optional

### R

- strong statistical focus
- object-oriented paradigm is pervasive
- mature/powerful plotting and graphics
- larger user base
- many user-contributed packages available
- syntax for entering/manipulating arrays seems clumsy
- code is relatively verbose
- more accessible and extensive documentation

If my major focus was statistical then I think R would be the obvious choice. 
However I find J's data manipulation features to be both simpler and more powerful. 
So my current have-my-cake-and-eat-it-too solution is to use J for creating and manipulating data, then use its Rserve interface to access features/packages from R as required. However so far my R usage has been "light".

- I found [this post describing R](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/06/0388.html) resonated with me.

Answer (score 3):

A few comments on J that weren't mentioned above re: loops.

A big focus in J is to define operations that are applied to an entire array in one go.  These operations are typically much faster than loops because of the behind-the-scenes optimisations that are possible then.

While you can do loops in J, often you can completely avoid them.  So, if you can change your problem solving approach, you can usually be much faster.  This *shift* can take a few months.  It isn't that hard to achieve though.